# Using << or >> to concatenate a unsigned char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, concatenation, unsigned

If I have this 2 arrays:

```
unsigned char bytes1[n];
unsigned char bytes2[m];
```

(`n` and `m` are arbitrary integer numbers) and I do this:

```
cout << bytes1 << bytes2;
```

I manage to display the content for this 2 arrays. Is it possible use this concept to concatenate this two arrays? Something like that:

```
usigned char bytes1[2];
unsigned char bytes2[3];
unsigned char * bytes3 = new unsigned char[5];
bytes3 << bytes1 << bytes2;
```

In the end, `bytes2` should have the content of `bytes1` and `bytes2` in sequence.

Comment: Use a `std::stringstream`.

Comment: No, C++ doesn't work this way. You have to construct an intermediate `std::ostringstream`, and then use `str()` to extract the composed string. But in that case it's going to be far easier to, you know, actually write C++ code, using C++ library classes, instead of dealing with C-style character arrays.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik but this arrays are not character arrays. I am using `unsigned char` because the content of this arrays are not alphanumeric characters, and aren't terminated with `\0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `stringstream` in this context.

referenced here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/?kw=stringstream

in the header:

```
#include <sstream>
```

in the body:

```
unsigned char bytes1[2];
unsigned char bytes2[3];
unsigned char * bytes3 = new unsigned char[5];

std::stringstream ss;
ss << bytes1 << bytes2;
ss >> bytes3

//This should be also good
std::string bytes3 = ss.str();
```

Your original code doesn't work because `byte3` isn't a `stream` (`ostream` specifically), so it doesn't have a `<<` operator